# R Plyr Sapply seems to be really slow

Tags: r, plyr, sapply

I thought I had a really simple dataframe transormation but for a reason I cannot fathom it seems to be taking an eternity which makes me suspect it probably isn't doing what I had hoped.  Can anyone shed some light?

***Part 1 - Transform source data into separate columns (actual df has 2.6M rows).***

Given...

```
> V1 <- c("E11 2286 1", "ECAT 2286 1", "M11 2286 1", "M12 2286 1", "MCAT 2286 1", "C24 2287 1")
> df <- data.frame(V1)
> df
           V1
1  E11 2286 1
2 ECAT 2286 1
3  M11 2286 1
4  M12 2286 1
5 MCAT 2286 1
6  C24 2287 1
```

I want to create two new columns (itemID & topic) and populate each column with a substr of corresponding row in V1.

This I can do using;

```
> require(stringr)
> df$itemID <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) str_split(df[i,"V1"]," ")[[1]][[2]] )
> df$topic  <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) str_split(df[i,"V1"]," ")[[1]][[1]] )
```

BUT this takes several minutes and seems like there should be a more efficient way.  So firstly I tried using sapply;

```
> sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
                                    t <- str_split(df[i,"V1"]," ")
                                    df$itemID <- t[[1]][[2]] 
                                    df$topic  <- t[[1]][[1]] 
                                  })
```

After over an hour, nothing.  So I bailed as this was obviously getting nowhere when individual commands would have taken under 20 minutes.

Next option was to try ddply on just a single task and this failed as well.

```
> require(plyr)
> require(stringr)
> df$itemID <- ddply(df, .(V1), str_split(df$V1," ")[[1]][[2]], .progress="text"  )

Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object '2286' of mode 'function' was not found
```

**So for part one of this task can anyone;**

- i) tell me which approach is likely to be quicker (sapply or ddply), and
- ii) using that approach provide a solution as to how to split column V1 into the two required component columns?

---

***Part 2 - Gather up all topics for an itemID***
For bonus points... The second part of the task I need is to take the 2.6M rows (now in 3 columns) and collapse each row for an itemID so that all the topics are held in a single cell.

The output should end up looking like...

```
  itemID    topic
1 2286      E11,ECAT,M11,M12,MCAT
2 2287      C24
```

**Can anyone suggest a simple method for such a gathering of rows into a single cell?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use a couple of options to improve the speed.

**1. stringi**

Functions in `stringi` package are usually faster.  We can extract the alphanumeric characters using `stri_extract_all_regex` with the appropriate `regex`.  Here, I am using `[[:alnum:]]{2,}` based on the example showed.  `rbind` the list elements (`do.call(rbind.data.frame,..)`), change the column names with `setNames`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), and `paste` the 'topic' elements grouped by 'itemID' (`toString`- is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=', ')`).

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
setDT(setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame,stri_extract_all_regex(df$V1,
       '[[:alnum:]]{2,}')), c('topic', 'itemID')))[, 
          list(topic=toString(topic)), itemID]
#   itemID                     topic
#1:   2286 E11, ECAT, M11, M12, MCAT
#2:   2287                       C24
```

**2. dplyr/tidyr**

We can use `extract` from `tidyr` to convert the single column to multiple columns by specifying the appropriate regex and `paste` the 'topic' elements grouped by 'itemID'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 extract(df, V1, into= c('topic', 'itemID'), '([^ ]+) ([^ ]+).*', 
                        convert=TRUE) %>% 
           group_by(itemID) %>% 
           summarise(topic=toString(topic))
#  itemID                     topic
#1   2286 E11, ECAT, M11, M12, MCAT
#2   2287                       C24
```

Comment: Wow... I was only just getting through trying to understand the first answer (which works as advertised for both parts of my problem).

So stringi & stringr are roughly equiv and using str_extract_all there is no execution speed difference.

I LOVE the second example using dplyr & tidyr as I've been trying to get to grips with those elsewhere in my project so more examples are better.

Super chap, very very helpful.

Comment: @BarneyC The `stringi` functions are very fast.  You may also try the `extract`, which should be fast as well. (not tested though)

Comment: I'll have a good look at the stringi package as it certainly seems to have a lot more methods baked in.  In this case no speed advantage (on 2.6M rows both execute in 0.2s!) but it may be far more flexible elsewhere.

Comment: I STAND CORRECTED... @akrun you are a genius!    Ran proper timings across the first method for all 2.6M rows.  Stringr 5.37mins vs Stringi 1.73mins (so 3x quicker).     Now to check the dlypr/tidyr method

Comment: @BarneyC Thanks for getting back with the benchmarks.  The persons who created these awesome packages are geniuses, not me :-)

Comment: Timings on the dplyr/tidyr method are full run in 57s for 2.6M rows which is hands down the quickest and (IMO) the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? Using [data.table v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table)
cols = c("topic", "itemID", "tmp")
setDT(df)[, c(cols) := tstrsplit(V1, " ", fixed=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)]
df[, .(topic=paste(topic, collapse=", ")), by=itemID]
#    itemID                     topic
# 1:   2286 E11, ECAT, M11, M12, MCAT
# 2:   2287                       C24
```

---

#### Benchmark on 2.6 million rows:

```
N = 2.6e6L
x = paste(rep(letters, length.out=N), sample(1e4, N, TRUE), "1", sep=" ")
dat = data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
nrow(dat) # 2.6 million

# dplyr+tidyr
system.time({ans1 <- extract(dat, x, into= c('topic', 'itemID'), 
         '([^ ]+) ([^ ]+).*', convert=TRUE) %>% 
          group_by(itemID) %>% 
         summarise(topic=toString(topic))})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  45.643   0.854  46.777 

# data.table
system.time({
    cols = c("topic", "itemID", "tmp")
    setDT(dat)[, c(cols) := tstrsplit(x, " ", fixed=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)]
    ans2 <- dat[, .(topic=paste(topic, collapse=", ")), by=itemID]
})    
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.906   0.064   1.981 

identical(as.data.frame(ans1), setDF(ans2[order(itemID)]))
# [1] TRUE
```

The speedup is **~24x**.

---

**Update:** Running `data.table` answer first and then `dplyr` answer results in run times of **7s** and **44s**, yielding a speedup of **~6.3x**. It seems like there is some cache efficiency in data.table method when run after `dplyr`.

Comment: I initially had the idea of `tstrsplit`, but then I thought `stringi` would be fast.  Thanks for the benchmark.